# How can i write checked event for input tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input tag where it has smart serach option that is suppose if i enter test in textbox and click on down arrow then i will get all the data related to test with checkboxes where i can check multiple items now i need to write an jquery function for this input tag to check whether they are checked or not how can i do this

Below is my input tag

```
<input id="ddldata" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: consol.log($('#ddldata').attr('checked')) try this

Comment: $('#ddldata').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        console.log('checked');
        return;
    }
    // not checked
});

Comment: but how can i write that for this html tag <input id="ddldata" autocomplete="off" /> i need to have som event know like onchecked or onchecked change know to writes the above code

Comment: @karalkunal can you show the structure of checkbox's DOM

Comment: First of all, the very first comment made needs to be addressed.  This question is not complete and cannot be answered until you do so.  Secondly, input elements require a type.  What type of input do you expect the browser to show?

Comment: by default it is taking type text

Comment: Never assume a default, unless you want the application to break when browser defaults change.  Specify a type.  Read the first comment and then come back and fix your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onchange event

```html
<input id="ddldata" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" onchange="somevent(this)"  />

<script>

function somevent(element){
  if($(element).prop("checked")){
    //write your code here
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: @karalkunal can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: i have a text box where i will enter any text in textbox after entering the text i will automatically get data with checkboxes where i can select single or multiple now i need to check whether they are checked or not using an event for this input tag <input id="ddldata" autocomplete="off" />